# Get data from DB2 with Flask Pyodbc with parameter

Tags: api, flask, db2, pyodbc

So, I was working on API with flask. The data is in DB2. I tried to connect with pyodbc as below

```
@app.route('/api/acrdkl/all', methods=['GET'])
def api_all():
    conn = pyodbc.connect("DSN=AS400;UID=....;PWD=....")
    cur = conn.cursor()
    all_books = cur.execute(""" select trim(dkkdcb), trim(dkkdps), trim(dkcob), trim(dkureg), trim(dkbktg), trim(dkblrg), trim(dkthrg)
    from simdta.ACRDKL where dkkdcb=1402 and dkblrg=10 and dkthrg=2020""")
    rows = cur.fetchall()
    result = []
    for dt in rows:
        result.append([x for x in dt])
    return jsonify(result)
```

Result are shown as JSON.

But when I tried to use some parameter as below

```
@app.route('/api/acrdkl/filter', methods=['GET'])
def api_filter():

    dkkdcb = request.args.get('DKKDCB', 0)
    dkblrg = request.args.get('DKBLRG', 0)
    dkthrg = request.args.get('DKTHRG', 0)

    query = """selecttrim(dkkdcb),trim(dkkdps),trim(dkcob),trim(dkureg),
    trim(dkbktg), trim(dkblrg), trim(dkthrg)
    from simdta.ACRDKL WHERE """

    conn = pyodbc.connect("DSN=AS400;UID=.....;PWD=.....")
    cur = conn.cursor()
    rows = cur.execute(query, [int(dkkdcb), int(dkblrg), int(dkthrg)])
    rows.fetchall()
    print("rows 2 ", rows)
    result = []
    for dt in rows:
        result.append([x for x in dt])
    return jsonify(results)
```

And I go to this `http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/acrdkl/filter?DKKDCB=1402&DKBLRG=10&DKTHRG=2020` and it throws error like this

> pyodbc.DataError: ('22023', '[22023] [Microsoft][ODBC DB2 Driver]Data
> exception - SQLSTATE 22023, SQLCODE -302. SQLSTATE: 22023, SQLCODE:
> -302 (-302) (SQLExecDirectW)')

How do I get the desired result? Where is my mistake? Any help would be appreciate. Thanks

Comment: Is it `dkkdcb_` or is it a typo?

Comment: Srry for that. Its typo

Comment: Share the table schema with its column data types

Comment: Its solved. I used `Replace` func for the query. Thanks anyway, Sir.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see that you are accessing the [request data provided by Flask](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/quickstart/#the-request-object), e.g.:

```
dkbrlg=request.args.get('dkbrlg',0)
```

Comment: I've tried the way you suggest as above, and still got the error. Am I missing something?

Comment: Have you tried with lower case? Parameters are normalized to lower case

Comment: Yes I did. Didnt work too. Whats funny is, if the parameter value is set, the result is shown. But if the parameter value is random, its not.